# Solr searching text with percentage sign '%'

Tags: java, spring, solr, solr9

I wanna make query into solr by searching values like '75%' or '14%' and etc. Generated query is `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/testEngine/query?q=250%25&q.op=OR&indent=true&start=0&rows=20`
The problem is that returned result rows contains text `250%` and `25/250` which is wrong and unexpected 
I see that its generate and additional 25 number but in other side %25 corresponds to the % character. Chrome also turns % or %25. Can it means that or Solr chokes on just a % because it expects a URL escape sequence or how it should be modified to return only text which contains like `250%`?

Comment: How the query is performed depends on what the analysis chain for the field is. Common filters will remove `%` or split by it - so what is the analysis chain for the field, and what does the `Analysis` page under the admin console show as the tokens when you input `250%`? - the `%25` part is just how it's escaped in the URL, and means that Solr will actually see `250%`, not `250%25` (`%25` => `%`). However, the analysis chain will probably remove that special character, again, depending on which filters are present in the analysis chain for that field.

Comment: @MatsLindh query have like an standart analyzers 
        `<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>`

Comment: @MatsLindh analysing query returns only 250, so % is trimmed from query

Comment: The StandardTokenizer will split on `%` as well, so if you want those to be kept, define a different field type with a whitespace tokenizer (or something else that matches how you want to tokenize text).